# Read .img file in python script

Tags: python

I have tried pycdlib and isoparser to read .img files which contain about hundred of images.
Both got error message.

pycdlib:

```
PyCdlibInvalidISO: Valid ISO9660 filesystems must have at least one PVD.
```

isoparser:

```
SourceError: Wrong volume descriptor identifier
```

Is there any problem with .img file?

Comment: What kind of `.img` file are you working with? Are you sure it's a CD image?

Comment: @duskwuff Sorry, I can't fully understand your question.
The filename extension is .img.
Is it possible that the .img file is not a CD image?
I can use winRAR and 7zip to open the .img file. But I need to read it in python script. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @duskwuff I use osx command to check file information.
and found that .img file is actually a rarfile.
So use the rarfile package can read it.
You're right. It's not a CD Image.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your image(s) file(s) doesn’t have *volume descriptors* defined in file’s structure, due for a corrupted file.

If you are using a Linux system, try inspect file with [*iso-info*](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-iso-info/) command.

Comment: I'm using windows system.
Is there any method to inspect .img file on Win system?
Btw the .img file is automatically generated  by Charge Coupled Device System.
I can use winRAR and 7zip to open the .img file.
But I need to read it in python script.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: After checking the file information, found that it actually a rarfile. So use rarfile package can read the file successfully.